# How do I change the CSS of an element based on returned data from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, css, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on a voting app using vanilla JS, Vue js, and Firebase. and I'm almost finished but I can't find a way to make the voting buttons have different colors when the user votes (just like YouTube's like and dislike buttons), so if the user leaves and come back again, the things they upvoted/downvoted stay colored.

This is my code so far...

index.js (cloud functions):

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


exports.newUserSignup = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user)=> {
   return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
        upVotedOn: [],
        downVotedOn: []
    })
});

exports.addRequest = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return admin.firestore().collection('requests').add({
        text: data.text,
        songN: data.songN,
        upVotes: 0,
        downVotes: 0,
    });
});

exports.upvote = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const user = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(context.auth.uid);
    const request = admin.firestore().collection('requests').doc(data.id);

    const doc = await user.get();

    if(doc.data().upVotedOn.includes(data.id)) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
            'failed-precondition', 'You can only upvote a song once'
        );
    }
    await user.update({
        upVotedOn: [...doc.data().upVotedOn, data.id]
    });
    
    return request.update({
        upVotes: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
        upColored: true
    });
});

exports.downvote = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const user = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(context.auth.uid);
    const request = admin.firestore().collection('requests').doc(data.id);

    const doc = await user.get();

    if(doc.data().downVotedOn.includes(data.id)) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
            'failed-precondition', 'You can only downvote a song once'
        );
    }
    await user.update({
        downVotedOn: [...doc.data().upVotedOn, data.id]
    });
    
    return request.update({
        downVotes: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
        downColored: true
    });
});
```

app.js (front end / vue js code):

```js
var form = document.querySelector(".form101");
var spotifyInput = document.getElementById("spotifyembd");
var songName = document.getElementById("songname")
var spotifyEmbed = document.getElementById("spotifyEmbed");
var songTitle = document.getElementById("title");
var up = document.getElementById("up");
var down = document.getElementById("down");

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#unitWrapper',
    data: {
        requests: [],
    },
    methods: {
        upV(id){
            const upvote = firebase.functions().httpsCallable("upvote");
            upvote({id: id})
            .catch(err => {
                showNotification();
            });
        },
        downV(id){
            const downvote = firebase.functions().httpsCallable("downvote");
            downvote({id: id})
            .catch(err => {
                showNotification();
            });
        }
    },
    mounted(){
    const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('requests').orderBy('upVotes', 'desc');
    ref.onSnapshot(snapshot => {

    let requests = [];
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        requests.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
    });
    this.requests = requests;
  });
}
});

form.addEventListener("submit", (e)=> {
    e.preventDefault();
    var songInput = `https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/${spotifyInput.value}`


    const addRequest = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addRequest');
    addRequest({
        text: songInput,
        songN: songName.value
    })
    .then(() => {
        form.reset();
    })
});

const notification = document.querySelector('.notification');
const showNotification = () => {
  notification.textContent = "You can only upvote or downvote a song once";
  notification.classList.add('active');
  setTimeout(() => {
    notification.classList.remove('active');
    notification.textContent = '';
  }, 4000);
};
```

It's a very simple app, I just need this feature so users don't get confused with what they did and didn't vote on, please help.

Comment: Vue is based on VNode mechanism. So uses [Vue: Style binding](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) instead of directly manipulating Dom will be the right approach. Otherwise, you have to struggle with all kinds of side effect during developing the app.

Answer (score 0):

Quite similar to what you have near the end for your notifications, you could do something like this:

var vote_state = (grab from firebase directly or with your API-style serverless request)

let item = document.querySelector('item');

const setVotedState = () => {
item.classList.add(`vote-${vote_state}`);

Then style the CSS of vote-up or vote-down for example to have different colors.

Answer (score 0):

With Vue you can conditionaly add style or class on elements based on data you provide in the data object of your vue instance :

- `<div v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }"></div>`
- `<div :class="{ active: isActive }"></div>`

or

- `<div v-bind:style="{ color: activeColor, fontSize: fontSize + 'px' }"></div>`
- `<div :style="{ color: activeColor, fontSize: fontSize + 'px' }"></div>`

It works the same way as key/value pair, key being the class or the css rule and the value an expression to control its existence.

isActive, activeColor, and fontSize or whatever you want it to be called being properties of the data object.

I would recommend reading this for more knowledge : https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes